# List domain names using host command in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Hi I'm working on a shell script to take in input from a file and using a for loop to run the host command on each IP and if it works it prints out the result that show the domain name but if the IP is not found it should print UNKNOWN. This is what I have so far.

hostlist file looks like:

```
72.247.244.88
173.231.140.219
65.55.72.135
97.107.137.164
69.171.224.11
199.59.149.230
174.121.194.34
```

My current code:

```
#! /bin/bash
for ips in /opt/book/list/results/hostlist

do
    hostnames=$(host $ips)
    if [[$hostnames == *"NXDOMAIN"*]]
        then echo "UNKNOWN"
    else echo $hostnames
    fi
done
```

What I want the results to look like:

```
230.149.59.xxx.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer www4.twitter.com.
230.149.59.xxx.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer www4.example.com.
UKNOWN
UNKOWN
230.149.59.xxx.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer www4.dummy.com.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with something like this

```
#! /bin/bash

while read ip; do
  hostname=`host $ip`
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo $hostname
  else
    echo "UNKNOWN"
  fi
done < /opt/book/list/results/hostlist
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you looking for something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ips in `cat /opt/book/list/results/hostlist`
do 
    hostname=$(eval host ${ips})

    if [[ "${hostname}" =~ "NXDOMAIN" ]]
        then 
            echo "UNKNOWN"
        else 
            echo ${hostname}
    fi
done
```

To iterate over the content of the file you have to read it in some way, therefore the `cat /opt/book/list/results/hostlist` on the for definition.

Besides that you also need to compare equal thing on your if putting the hostname var inside double quotes so bash understand that the variable and the text "NXDOMAIN" are the same.

Last to check if the string exists in the variable you can use the `=~` function,  it checks if the right parameter exists inside the left.

Hope it helps.